# Function to conditionally set a variable read-only

Tags: bash, shell-script, variable, readonly, declare

If I had a script which sets variables read-only to some odd values, and sets `errexit` because of other unsafe operations:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
set -e 
declare -r NOTIFY=$(case "$OS" in (macosx) echo macos_notify ;; (linux) echo linux_notify ;; (*) echo : ;; esac)
declare -r SAY=_say # _say is a function
declare -r VERSION=0.99
set +e
```

And I source it to get the definitions, the second time because it's in development:

```bash
$ . s.bash 

$ . s.bash 
bash: declare: NOTIFY: readonly variable
Exited
```

Normally `declare -r EXISTING_VAR` would neither stop the script nor remove the old, working definition of `EXISTING_VAR`.

But with `errexit`, assigning to an existing variable is understandably a failure. The easy options are to remove `-r` or use `set +e` for that part of the script.

Barring those, **is it possible to write a Bash function to take the place of `declare -r` but not re-assign if the name already exists**?

I tried:

```bash
# arg #1: var name, #2: value
set_var_once () {
  # test whether the variable with the 
  # name stored in $1 exists 
  if [[ -z "${!1}" ]] 
  then # if it doesn't, set it
    declare -r $1=$2
  fi
}
```

I also tried things along the lines of `eval "declare -r $1=$(eval $2)"`, it feels like `eval` is required somewhere here but I'm not sure where.

All of the versions of `set_var_once` result in not setting the variable they should.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`declare -r` make a variable readonly but also *declares* it in the current scope and so makes it local to the current function. You'd want `readonly` instead that only does the former:

```
readonly_once() {
  local __assign
  for __assign do
    [[ -v ${__assign%%=*} ]] || readonly "$__assign"
  done
}
```

To be used as:

```
readonly_once VAR1=foo VAR2="$(cmd)" PATH ...
```

Note that since contrary to `readonly`, that `readonly_once` is not a keyword (yes, `readonly` is *also* a keyword even though `bash` keeps that fact hidden), that `$(cmd)` needs to be quoted to prevent split+glob, it's not an assignment at that point.

`$(cmd)` will be expanded (and so `cmd` run) even if the value will end-up not being assigned to `VAR2` if it was already defined.

That function only works for scalar variables, not arrays nor associative arrays.

Answer (score 2):

If your shell is bash, you can use the `-v` `test`:

```
[[ -v NOTIFY ]]  || NOTIFY=$(case "$OS" in (macosx) echo macos_notify ;; (linux) echo linux_notify ;; (*) echo : ;; esac)
[[ -v SAY ]]     || SAY=_say # _say is a function
[[ -v VERSION ]] || VERSION=0.99
```

For example

```
$ unset myvar
$ [[ -v myvar ]] && echo "already set to $myvar" || myvar=10
$ [[ -v myvar ]] && echo "already set to $myvar" || myvar=10
already set to 10
$ myvar=5
$ [[ -v myvar ]] && echo "already set to $myvar" || myvar=10
already set to 5
$ myvar=""
$ [[ -v myvar ]] && echo "already set to $myvar" || myvar=10
already set to
```

---

Or, use the `${param:=value}` expansion and the `:` command

```
: ${NOTIFY:=$(case "$OS" in (macosx) echo macos_notify ;; (linux) echo linux_notify ;; (*) echo : ;; esac)}
: ${SAY:=_say}
: ${VERSION:=0.99}
```

demonstrating:

```
$ OS=macosx
$ echo "$NOTIFY"

$ : ${NOTIFY:=$(case "$OS" in (macosx) echo macos_notify ;; (linux) echo linux_notify ;; (*) echo : ;; esac)}
$ echo "$NOTIFY"
macos_notify
$ NOTIFY=no
$ : ${NOTIFY:=$(case "$OS" in (macosx) echo macos_notify ;; (linux) echo linux_notify ;; (*) echo : ;; esac)}
$ echo "$NOTIFY"
no
$ NOTIFY=""
$ : ${NOTIFY:=$(case "$OS" in (macosx) echo macos_notify ;; (linux) echo linux_notify ;; (*) echo : ;; esac)}
$ echo "$NOTIFY"
macos_notify
```

Comment: The `-v` test may have appeared in a recent bash version, I don't know.

Comment: I considered the `$(param:=value}` thing but discarded it lacking support for `declare -r` / `readonly`

Comment: Well do you want read-only or not? Are you really asking us how to assign to a read-only variable?

Comment: I'm asking how *not* to assign to a readonly variable if it's set. I ended up using the `[[ -v VAR ]] || declare -r VAR=` thing anyway :)

Comment: Ah, I see. Well we can ask the shell if the variable is readonly: `[[ -v VAR ]] && [[ "$(declare -p VAR)" == "declare -r"* ]] && echo "can't set readonly variable"` -- now, if you declare the variable with other attributes (e.g. `declare -ri answer=42`) then you may need to adjust that pattern.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the following to be useful

```
# Function SetCommand
# Function to find a command and assign the absolute path of that command to
# a variable.  The intent is to only invoke known good commands.
# If a command is not found, abort.  Assume the script needed this command.
# Function is called as follows:
#     SetCommand assignmentVariableName queryString
#
# where
#     assignmentVariableName is the name of the variable to which the path
# is assigned,
#     queryString is the name of the command
#
# Example: SetCommand CMD_FOO foo
#
SetCommand() {
    local _assignmentVariableName
    local _fullPath
    local _queryString

    [ $# -ne 2 ] && AbortScript "${FUNCNAME}: Invalid number of arguments."

    _assignmentVariableName="$1"
    [[ "" == "${_assignmentVariableName}" ]] && AbortScript "${FUNCNAME}: assignmentVariableName is blank."
    shift

    _queryString="$1"
    [[ "" == "${_queryString}" ]] && AbortScript "${FUNCNAME}: queryString is blank."
    shift

    if [[ ! -z ${!_assignmentVariableName+x} ]]; then
        Print2Stderr "${FUNCNAME}: ${_assignmentVariableName} already defined."
        return ${constErrorExitCode}
    fi

    _fullPath=$(${CMD_WHICH} ${_queryString} 2>/dev/null)
    [[ "" == "${_fullPath}" ]] && AbortScript "${FUNCNAME}: Could not find command, ${_queryString}."

    eval readonly ${_assignmentVariableName}=${_fullPath}

    return ${constSuccessExitCode}
} # End SetCommand
```

The AbortScript is another function I use.  It just prints out the error message and then exits the script.

Comment: This doesn't appear to work, I still get `bash: NOTIFY: readonly variable` but this time from `readonly` rather than from `declare`. Remember, it needs to survive being re-`source`d  with the same readonly names pre-declared

Comment: Sorry about that.  I copied my original snippet from an older script.  I have updated the above.  Please try now.